# Converting HoA to HoH with counting

Tags: perl

Have this code:

```
use 5.020;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h = (
    k1 => [qw(aa1 aa2 aa1)],
    k2 => [qw(ab1 ab2 ab3)],
    k3 => [qw(ac1 ac1 ac1)],
);

my %h2;
for my $k (keys %h) {
    $h2{$k}{$_}++ for (@{$h{$k}});
}
say Dumper \%h2;
```

produces:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'k1' => {
                    'aa2' => 1,
                    'aa1' => 2
                  },
          'k3' => {
                    'ac1' => 3
                  },
          'k2' => {
                    'ab1' => 1,
                    'ab3' => 1,
                    'ab2' => 1
                  }
        };
```

Is possible to write the above code with "another way"? (e.g. simpler or more compact)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, I don't like the number of times `$h2{$k}` is evaluated.

```
my %h2;
for my $k (keys %h) {
   my $src = $h{$k};
   my $dst = $h2{$k} = {};
   ++$dst->{$_} for @$src;
}
```

A subroutine can help make the intent more obvious. Maybe.

```
sub counts { my %c; ++$c{$_} for @_; \%c }

$h2{$_} = counts(@{ $h{$_} }) for keys %h;
```

That can be simplified if you do the change in-place.

```
sub counts { my %c; ++$c{$_} for @_; \%c }

$_ = counts(@$_) for values %h;
```

Comment: Exactly wanted such answer. Now will spend the next two (or more) hours with trying to understand it. ;) :)

Comment: @ikegami I am little confused with the `$_ = counts(@$_) for values %h;`. Would you mind adding a little explanation on how can we make that useful? We are assigning the counts returned by sub-routine to an array reference ...

Comment: `$_` is an alias to the value of the current element of `%h`, so `$_ = counts(@$_) for values %h;` is basically `$h{$_} = counts(@{ $h{$_} }) for keys %h;`